# PHP Best Way To Assign Var Value In Object Class

Tags: php, class, oop

I just wonder what is the best way to assign default value in PHP Class.

Example:
The PHP constructor `__construct()` method is the first method will be read whenver the class is called. So here's some code:

```
class A{
   private $x;

   public function __construct(){
       //Var x iniated in constructor method
       $this->x = "some values";
   }
}
```

Example above I put `x` variable to "some values" in constructor method.

And I tried this (below codes) too and it works the same.

```
class A{
    private $x = "some values";

    public function __construct(){
        //Var x initiated out of constructor method
    }
}
```

My question is, which one is the best practice?

Comment: If the value is a literal (string, numerical value, array), put it in the variable declaration. If it is an expression (function call, calculation), put it in the constructor.

Comment: If $x is always the same, you should do it as in the second case you posted. If the value should be browsable like $here->x then make it public. Otherwise make  it private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Use default values as much as possible for readability, when you can't assign value as default, use function to set it.

---

If you are using static method, then no `__construct` will be called, so your value will be not set.

If it's literal value, it's best to set it as default value (`private $x = 'some value'`), otherwise use constructor/setter/factory methods for this value to be set:

```
private static $x;

public function getX() {
    if (empty(self::$x)) {
        self::$x = new XClass();
    }

    return self::$x;
}

public function randomTest() {
    $x = $this->getX()->callMethod()->doStuff();
}
```